# Scratch Application(MIT)

Tags: mit-scratch, scratch-file, scratchbox

In the Scratch application, how can I change the download directory to any other location when I click "save the file to the computer"? Additionally, I would like to save the project file to a back end database using Node.js. Where can I access the project.sb3 file when I click "save the file to the computer"?

I'm expecting default directory coded file and finding that .sb2 .sb3 file generating js file in scratch application

Answer (score 0):

The location where the Scratch projects are saved is determined by your browser.

For example, in my Firefox, you can go to the "Settings" page, find "Downloads" and change that folder to whatever you want to use. Alternatively, check the "Always ask you where to save files" checkbox to specify the folder later.